# JUnit testing - Hw can I set up my DB connect to avoid tests failing due to maximum DB connection reached

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, junit, dropwizard

I am doing some DAO testing in Java, and I have defined a class that sets the connection to the testing DB like this

```
import io.dropwizard.testing.ResourceHelpers;
import io.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardAppRule;
import my.project.package.ProjectTestAppConfiguration;
import my.project.package.ProjectTestApplication;
import my.project.package.domain.ProjectClass1;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.junit.ClassRule;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;

public class DAOTestConfig {
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @ClassRule
    public static final DropwizardAppRule<ProjectTestAppConfiguration> RULE =
    new DropwizardAppRule<ProjectTestAppConfiguration>
    (ProjectTestApplication.class, ResourceHelpers.resourceFilePath("applicationTest.yml"));

    public DAOTestConfig() {
        Map<String, String> properties = RULE.getConfiguration().getDataSourceFactory().getProperties();
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> property : properties.entrySet()) {
            configuration.setProperty(property.getKey(), property.getValue());
        }

        /* Add annotated classes here */

        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(ProjectClass1.class);

        /* ... */

        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        Session session;
        try{
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (SessionException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }
}
```

My `applicationTest.yml` file contains standard db connection, like

```
     # Database settings.
        database:

          # the name of your JDBC driver
          driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

          # the username for DB
          user: ${FH_DB_USER}

          # the password
          password: ${FH_DB_PASSWORD}

          # the JDBC URL
          url: jdbc:postgresql://${FH_DB_HOST}:${FH_DB_PORT}/${FH_DB_NAME}

          # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
          properties:
            charSet: UTF-8
            hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
            hibernate.connection.driver_class: org.postgresql.Driver
            hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
            hibernate.connection.url: jdbc:postgresql://${FH_DB_HOST}:${FH_DB_PORT}/${FH_DB_NAME}
            hibernate.connection.username: ${FH_DB_USER}
            hibernate.connection.password: ${FH_DB_PASSWORD}
            hibernate.current_session_context_class: thread
            hibernate.show_sql: true
```

I currently have more than twenty test case classes that have an average of 5 test cases in each, that connects to the DB. As you can see, I am using dropwizard and hibernate in my procts; my DAO classes use hibernate C-R-U-D (crate, read, updte, delete) methods, and the connections are made to a postgres DB. And each class `extends` this `DAOTestConfig` class.
I was running the test on my local michine but I want to use a remote DB instance, and now some of my tests are failing with the error `Error calling Driver#connect`

Here is an example of the stack trace of one of the tests that failed:

```
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildBootstrapJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.getBootstrapJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:71)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.use42Api(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:83)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at my.project.package.persistence.DAOTestConfig.<init>(DAOTestConfig.java:106)
    at my.project.package.persistence.ProjectClass1DAOTest.<init>(ProjectClass1DAOTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:691)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc42.AbstractJdbc42Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc42Connection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.<init>(Jdbc42Connection.java:28)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 50 more
```

On my local machine I added a work around on this to make all my tests pass, by changing the maximum connection number from 100 to 300, but now that I want to find a permanent solution in case that number become small in the future. And there are other project that will be using that same remote DB instance.

I have googled for the solution to this but I can't find it. Either there is none or I am asking the wrong question. Can anyone help me on this?

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend using a virtual machine to test a remote connection. To automate this process you might want to have a look at `vagrant` and `ansible`. Vagrant hosts your vm and ansible sets it up with whatever you would like. A quick guide: https://yobriefca.se/blog/2015/05/20/provisioning-postgres-via-vagrant-and-ansible/ | If you need specific settings in your production environment you should define this as a requirement and inform the appropriate people to make the necessary changes. Also: Shouldn't you close the `sessionFactory` after you are done with it?

Comment: Do you use a connection pool? In general, it's a good practice to keep connection pool small and JDBC connection concurrency high. Even 100 connections are kinda overkilling.

Comment: @DmitrySavinkov I don't use a connection pull. The class I posted in my question is all I do to connect to the db.

Comment: @showp1984 my instance is on aws. I don't know if that counts as a virtual machine, and I am integrating my test in jenkins. I guess I should've added that before hand when asking my question

Answer (score 1):

> Hw can I set up my DB connect to avoid tests failing due to maximum DB connection reached

When UnitTesting you do not connect to a database.

You *mock* the classes that do the actual database connection and configure them to return well defined values suitable for your test case. In order to do that you may use a mocking framework like *Mockito* or alike.

Also UnitTest verify behavior of *your own code*. Your Test verifies the behavior of the  code that connects to the database and this looks like some Framework you use. This would only be needed if you don't trust that framework, but if it is not trustworthy, why do you use it then?

Comment: Yes indeed I use the mockito framework to mock the DAOs in the services, when I'm testing HTTP request that fetch data for my UI. It's not been long since I started testing java code, or programming with java language. Most of the code I looked at that tests DAOs connect to the DB. But I will research further on this. One more this is that the some DAOs return an object with a lot of data especially if my POJO have `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` annotations, that would be a pain to put, say like in a file, and read them from there. But I guess it'll be easy than connecting to DB.